# text-decoration not working

Tags: css, text, underline, text-decorations

Why are the post titles underlined even though `h2` element has `text-decoration: none` as a description?

Comment: The ones with the default `ANCHOR` with no `a:link {text-decoration: none;}` style declaration? I would say it's the `ANCHOR` and default browser behavior (most browsers default to underlining links).

Comment: I removed the dead link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the text-decoration to none on the `a`

```
h2 a {text-decoration:none;}
```